# How can I prevent empty lines between lists from causing org-mode to insert blank lines before new items?

Tags: org-mode

Here is an illustration of the problem:

```
 - First item. Pressing M-RET...
 - Another item at the correct position. Now a blank line:

 - Next item after blank line. Now press M-RET again...

 - .. but now I'm down here!
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure that using the `org-blank-before-new-entry` variable.

I have set that to `'((heading) (plain-list-item))` so that such blank lines are not auto-inserted after `M-RET` for headings and list items.

You can also set just the `cdr` of the element with `plain-list-item` to nil to get exactly what want by doing:

```el
(setcdr (assoc 'plain-list-item org-blank-before-new-entry) nil)
```

---

Have a look at `C-h v org-blank-before-new-entry` output.

> Should `org-insert-heading` leave a blank line before new heading/item? 
>   The value is an alist, with `heading` and `plain-list-item` as CAR, 
>   and a boolean flag as CDR.  The cdr may also be the symbol `auto`, in 
>   which case Org will look at the surrounding headings/items and try to 
>   make an intelligent decision whether to insert a blank line or not.

It's default value is

```
'((heading . auto) (plain-list-item . auto))
```

So what are are seeing is expected.. as you had a blank line before the "- Next item after blank line. Now press M-RET again..." list item, it inserted a blank line before "- .. but now I'm down here!" too.